# Python, print letters and tower of asterisk equal to how many times the letter appears

Tags: python

```
def muchbetter(x):
    count_list = []
    for char in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
        count_list.append(x.lower().count(char))
    return tuple(count_list)


def print_stars(x):
    tup = muchbetter(x)
    stars = [' '*(max(tup) - s) + '*'*s for s in tup if s != 0] 
    print('\n'.join([''.join(a) for a in list(zip(*stars))]))
```

so those are two functions, the first one counts how many times a letter appears in a sample text, the second one makes a "tower of asterisk" equal to the number of letters, however, i need the second one to also put all of the letters at the bottom, so what i want it to do is

```
   *
*  *
ABCDEFGHIJLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

that should be the result if i input "ADD" as X, it would put two asterisk on top of X, 1 asterisk on top of A, and no asterisk ontop of anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You need just to delete `if s!= 0` in your list comprehension to make empty space for letters which are not in output of `muchbetter`.

```
def muchbetter(x):
    count_list = []
    for char in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
        count_list.append(x.lower().count(char))
    return tuple(count_list)


def print_stars_order(x):
    tup = muchbetter(x)
    stars = [' '*(max(tup) - s) + '*'*s for s in tup]
    print('\n'.join([''.join(a) for a in list(zip(*stars))]))
    print('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')


in_str="ADD" 
print_stars_order(in_str)

   *                      
*  *                      
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```